# Does anyone had ever successfully utilized CUDAfy in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, cudafy.net

I´m trying to utilize CUDAFy 1.29 in VB.NET using VS2013.

I´m trying to translate the samples of C# from CUDAFy and I´m having two type of errors, like explained below:

**My Variables**

```
Shared cs_CC As String = "adiciona"
Shared MyGPU As GPGPU = Nothing
Shared Arch As eArchitecture = Nothing
```

**My Code:**

```
 Shared Executa()

 if Loader = true

        Dim Modulo = CudafyModule.TryDeserialize(cs_cc)
        If IsNothing(Modulo) OrElse (Not Modulo.TryVerifyChecksums) Then
            Modulo = CudafyTranslator.Cudafy(ePlatform.All, Arch, cs_CC.GetType)
            Modulo.Serialize()
        End If

        MyGPU.Loadmodule(Modulo)

        Dim a As Integer() = New Integer(N - 1) {}
        Dim b As Integer() = New Integer(N - 1) {}
        Dim c As Integer() = New Integer(N - 1) {}

        ' allocate the memory on the GPU
        Dim dev_a As Integer() = MyGPU.Allocate(Of Integer)(a)
        Dim dev_b As Integer() = MyGPU.Allocate(Of Integer)(b)
        Dim dev_c As Integer() = MyGPU.Allocate(Of Integer)(c)

        ' fill the arrays 'a' and 'b' on the CPU
        For i As Integer = 0 To N - 1
            a(i) = i
            b(i) = 2 * i
        Next

        ' copy the arrays 'a' and 'b' to the GPU
        MyGPU.CopyToDevice(a, dev_a)
        MyGPU.CopyToDevice(b, dev_b)


        For i As Integer = 0 To 128
            MyGPU.Launch(1, 1).adiciona(dev_a, dev_b, dev_c)
        Next

 end if
```

End Sub

**The function ADICIONA which would run on CUDA**

```
 <Cudafy()> _
  Shared Sub adiciona(thread As GThread, a As Integer(), b As Integer(), c As Integer())

    Dim tid As Integer = thread.blockIdx.x
    While tid < N
        c(tid) = a(tid) + b(tid)
        tid += thread.gridDim.x
    End While
   End Sub
```

**LOADER: try to identify card and CUDA (successfully running):**

```
Public Shared Function Loader() As Boolean

    DeviceType = eGPUType.Cuda
    CudafyModes.Target = DeviceType
    CudafyTranslator.Language = If(CudafyModes.Target = eGPUType.Cuda, eLanguage.Cuda, eLanguage.OpenCL)
    Dim CompatibleDevice As GPGPUProperties() = CudafyHost.GetDeviceProperties(CudafyModes.Target, True).ToArray

    If Not CompatibleDevice.Any Then        '  não possui um full-CUDA device
        MsgBox("I do not found any OpenCL or CUDA compatible device")
        Return False
    End If

    Dim selectedDevice As GPGPUProperties = CompatibleDevice(0)
    If IsNothing(selectedDevice) Then
        MsgBox("I cannot allocate a compatible device")
        Return False
    End If


    CudafyModes.DeviceId = selectedDevice.DeviceId
    Thread_per_Block = selectedDevice.MaxThreadsPerBlock
    Blocks_per_Grid = selectedDevice.MaxThreadsSize.x
    Shared_Mem_per_Block = selectedDevice.SharedMemoryPerBlock

    MyGPU = CudafyHost.GetDevice(CudafyModes.Target, CudafyModes.DeviceId)
    Arch = MyGPU.GetArchitecture

    Return True

 End Function
```

The problems:

**Problem 1:** If I utilize just *dim Modulo as CudafyModule = CudafyTranslator.Cudafy()* I get the following error: **Checked Statements are not supported.** It´s weird! All documentation of Cudafy shows this line exactly as it!

**Problem 2:** So, I try to check the existence of a written module (.CDFY) and, if does not exist, I call the Serialize() function. The problem is the function creates a file called *STRING.CDFY* in my folder, but not the *ADICIONA.CDFY* nor *ADD_LONG_LOOP.CDFY*, which would be correct. Since I would like to avoid compilation at every run of this code, how to correctly make CUDAFy to write it?

**Problem 3:** When VS runs, everything goes OK until the point of calling ADICIONA (MyGPU.Launch)! VS stops the execution with a message "*COULD NOT FIND FUNCTION 'ADICIONA' IN MODULE*".

Interesting to notice that:

1- both temporary files are created (.CU, .PTX) and also the .CDFY file. It evidences the NVCC compiler is running well and creating the CUDA modules. So, why the code is NOT finding the function ADICIONA?

2- All samples written in C# run here 100%. And the conversion from C# and VB seems to be OK (I had utilized TELERIK to do it). I don´t guess the problem may be related to this, but I may be wrong.

3- The problem is NOT related to neither with NVCC compiler nor some reference into VB.NET, since the code compiles.

I tried to write in CODEPLEX for an answer. No answers at all...
I tried to see a lot of samples in Internet, but ALL OF THEM are created to CUDAFy C# and none of them are utilizing version 1.29 and CUDA 7.5.

Also, I would like to understand WHY the basic function (CudafyTranslator.Cudafy()) get an error in VB but not in C#.

So, does anyone here had successfully created a CUDAFy code using VB.NET?

Thank you VERY much for any help.

Comment: Where is the MyGPU.LoadModule(Modulo) ? You seem to be missing that part from the code sample.

Comment: Thanks @Mystra007, I only forgot to put it into my above post. I will provide the update now but I ensure to you that the problem is not related to this.

Answer (score 0):

To solve Problem 1, check "Remove integer overflow checks" under Project Properties > Compile > Advanced Compile Options > Optimizations. More info: http://forums.asp.net/post/715302.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple example:

```
Imports Cudafy
Imports Cudafy.Host
Imports Cudafy.Translator

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim GPU As GPGPU = CudafyHost.GetDevice(eGPUType.OpenCL, CudafyModes.DeviceId)
        Dim Modulo As CudafyModule = CudafyTranslator.Cudafy(ePlatform.All, GPU.GetArchitecture())

        GPU.LoadModule(Modulo)

        Dim Resultado As Integer
        Dim ResultadoGPU As Integer() = gpu.Allocate(Of Integer)()

        GPU.Launch().Adicionar(2, 7, ResultadoGPU)
        GPU.CopyFromDevice(ResultadoGPU, Resultado)
        MessageBox.Show("2 + 7 = " & Resultado)

        GPU.Launch().Subtrair(2, 7, ResultadoGPU)
        GPU.CopyFromDevice(ResultadoGPU, Resultado)
        MessageBox.Show("2 - 7 = " & Resultado)

        GPU.Free(ResultadoGPU)
    End Sub

    <Cudafy()>
    Private Shared Sub Adicionar(a As Integer, b As Integer, c As Integer())
        c(0) = a + b
    End Sub

    <Cudafy()>
    Private Shared Sub Subtrair(a As Integer, b As Integer, c As Integer())
        c(0) = a - b
    End Sub
End Class
```